# Irreducible integral polynomials having roots module primes in arithmetic progressions

Tags: polynomials, algebraic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $f(x)$ be an irreducible polynomial with integer coefficients. One can show (see  [Exercise 7.2 in this paper of Lenstra](https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/Lenstra-Chebotarev.pdf)) that if $f(x)=0$ has a solution mod $p$ for all but finitely many primes $p$, then $f(x)$ is linear. My question is the following: suppose we know that aside from a finite set of primes, the equation $f(x)=0$ has a root mod $p$ if and only if $p$ is congruent to $1$ mod 4.

1. Can one say anything useful about $f(x)$?
2. More specifically, are there polynomials other than $f(x)=x^2+1$ (up to linear change of coordinates) for which this property holds?
3. If the answer is yes, are there more general results of this sort characterizing polynomials based on the set of primes $p$ for which a solution mod $p$ exists?

Comment: Your questions is roughly equivalent to the question of, for a group $G$ acting transitively on a finite set $S$, if the set of elements with a fixed point form a finite subgroup of index $2$, must $S$ have two elements? I don't know the answer to this off the top of my head though.

Comment: @WillSawin I think the answer to your question is no (or I might have misunderstood something): The dihedral group $D_8$ acts transitively on the set of left cosets $D_8/\langle r\rangle$, where $r$ is a reflection. The set of elements having a fixed point has index $2$, but $D_8/\langle r\rangle$ has $4$ elements.

Comment: @KasperAndersen The set of elements having a fixed point is not a subgroup, instead consisting of some reflections and the identity, but no rotations.

Comment: @WillSawin Aah, I missed that you only looked at the *set* of elements having a fixed point, not the subgroup generated by this set.... :-( Sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that $f$ must be linearly equivalent to $x^2+1$. Indeed, let $K$ be a root field of (the irreducible polynomial) $f$. The assumption is that, for all but finitely many primes $p$, there is a prime of degree $1$ over $p$ in $K$ iff there is one in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$. Under these conditions, $K$ and $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ are called *Kronecker equivalent*. A result by Saxl (On a Question of W. Jehne Concerning Covering Subgroups of Groups and Kronecker Classes of Fields, J. London Math. Soc. (2) 38 (1988), 243-249) says that this is impossible unless $K=\mathbb{Q}(i)$ (and the same result holds when $\mathbb{Q}(i)$ is replaced by any quadratic number field). As mentioned by Will Sawin, the statement translates to saying that an index-2 normal subgroup in a transitive group cannot equal the union of all point stabilizers. Notably, Saxl states that his proof uses the classification of finite simple groups, so I don't know whether an elementary argument (even just for the special case $\mathbb{Q}(i)$) would be available.

PS: Just to expand a bit in the direction of Question 3): In general, Kronecker equivalent fields can be  more diverse. For example, already in $G=A_4$ acting on $6$ points, the union of all point stabilizers equals the normal index-$3$ subgroup $V_4$, which means that if $f$ and $g$ are (sextic and cubic) polynomials parameterizing the degree-$6$ and degree-$3$ subextensions of an $A_4$-extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ respectively, then existence of mod-$p$ roots of $f$ and of $g$ is equivalent for all but finitely many primes $p$.

Comment: If I may ask a follow up question: is it true that there are at most finitely many fields that are  Kronecker equivalent to a given algebraic number field?

Comment: @Keivan Karai: No, the Kronecker (equivalence) class of a given number field can be infinite. However the number of *minimal* (with respect to inclusion) fields in such a class is always finite. All dealt with in W. Jehne, Kronecker classes of algebraic number fields (1977).